# Blender freezes after a few seconds of interaction

Tags: error

I've had blender for a few days now and it has been running perfectly fine. But today after a few minutes of playing with the starter cube, blender freezes. After restarting, so much as a click freezes it.

There is no "not responding" message. When moving the window, the screen goes black. After leaving it frozen for an hour, nothing has changed and the only way to close it is through task manager.

Sometimes, even though the screen freezes, the cursor still updates, like the double arrow to resize window.

I'm fairly certain it has nothing to do with my PC's specs because, as mentioned, I've been working on it for a few days now and things have been fine.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and installing blender again?

Comment: @Ash I have. I've also tried installing an older version, but the same thing happens.

Comment: It could be, that you have outdated drivers or your ram is not handling the load